# change data based on vlookup result using vba userform

Tags: vba, excel

Afternoon guys,
I cannot find a way to code the following and I do not have any code to show.
I have a small and simple userform that displays a permit expiry date based on a combo box selection using vlookup.

[Screen grab of userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0OnJ.png)

What I need is to be able to change the date and write that new date back to appropriate cell in the database when hitting the command button on the left. The command button on the right just unloads the form. The form will be used to change the permit expiry date, which is required in a different database to control competition points allocation.

The code that I do have for this userform is as follows (This code is working fine):

```
Private Sub CmdChangedate_Click()

           'This is where the code will be
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me

End Sub

'This is where the name is selected from a combobox and the date is located
Private Sub Hengelaar_Change()
With Me
On Error Resume Next

.Nuwepermitdatum =    Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CStr(Me.Hengelaar), Worksheets("Lede Lys").Range("A:J"), 10, 0)

On Error GoTo 0

End With

End Sub

Private Sub Nuwepermitdatum_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal CallbackField As String, CallbackDate As Date)


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Me.Nuwepermitdatum.Value = Date
Hengelaar.List = Worksheets("Lede Lys").Range("a3:a" & lastrow).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you’re after:

```
Private Sub CmdChangedate_Click()
    With Worksheets("Lede Lys")
        .Cells(Application.Match(Me.Hengelaar, .Range("A:A"),0), "J") = Me.Nuwepermitdatum
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.